# How to remove the special characters for PostgreSQL sql query

Tags: postgresql

As per my analysis, I found that some special characters coming when we import a query result to CSV.But we are not found that in the database

I am using pgadmin client for writing the Postgresql query. Also attaching the result I got from pgadmin and after importing to CSV file

[image: from pgadmin]

[image: csv file]

Comment: You used the wrong client encoding when you imported the CSV file.

Comment: can you please give me the solution.I used pgadmin for importing csv file

Comment: I never use pgAdmin, but if you tell me the encoding the file is in (UTF-8 ?), I can tell you how to import it with `psql`.

Comment: CSV file is encoded in UTF-8

Comment: If you want to import from a file on the client, use `\copy tab FROM 'csvfile' (FORMAT 'csv', ENCODING 'UTF8')`